# Wagtail: Dynamically load StreamField blocks in the admin EditView

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have a use case where we need dynamic blocks for a `StreamField`. Unfortunately this doesn't seem possible, since block types are specified in the model's `StreamField` field.

I dug through the FieldPanel, StreamBlock and GroupPanel code and cannot clearly find a way to override the available blocks for the StreamField outside the model definition.

This is my current admin `EditView`, where you can see what I'm trying to accomplish (see the **NOTE/FIXME** comments below:

```py
class EditProductView(EditView):

    def get_edit_handler(self):
        summary_panels = [
            FieldPanel('title'),
            FieldPanel('description'),
            FieldPanel('body'),
        ]

        attributes_panel = [
            # NOTE/FIXME: This is where we need the custom blocks to load, based
            # on `self.instance.product_type`.

            FieldPanel('attributes'),

            # StreamFieldPanel (which is deprecated) does not work because you can
            # only set the blocks within the model, when defining the StreamFieldPanel.
            # I would love to be able to do something like:

            StreamFieldPanel('attributes', block_types=[
                ('test', blocks.CharBlock()),   # Like this for example
            ])

        ]

        settings_panels = [
            FieldPanel('categories'),
            StateMachinePanel('state', sm_prop='sm', heading="State"),
        ]

        return TabbedInterface([
            ObjectList(summary_panels, heading='Summary'),
            ObjectList(attributes_panel, heading='Attributes'),
            ObjectList(settings_panels, heading='Settings'),
        ]).bind_to_model(self.model_admin.model)
```

Is it possible to override available StreamField blocks in this way, or are there potential issues with `json_field` DB integrity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't work, because the StreamField block definition isn't just used for the edit form - any time you access that field, even just to output it on a template, the StreamField needs to look at the block definition to unpack the JSON and return the appropriate Python objects. For example, suppose the database contained:

```
[{'type': 'test', 'value': 123}]
```

What should `page.attributes[0].value` return? If the `test` block is of type `IntegerBlock`, it would return `123` - but if it was a `PageChooserBlock` instead, it would return the `Page` instance with ID 123. If it was an `ImageChooserBlock`, it would return the `Image` instance with ID 123, and so on. In your example, the only way to find out the block type is to call `get_edit_handler` and construct the entire editing interface as a side effect - this would be mixing up model-level logic with admin interface code, and be massively inefficient just for accessing a single field.

Comment: I was somewhat afraid that would be the answer. I'll need to go back to the drawing board in that case.